# Обработка исключений при взаимодействии с Twitter Api

Tags: c#, исключения

Есть строка кода `var requestToken = service.GetRequestToken();` у которой надо обработать исключение. Для этого надо создать и инициализировать переменную requestToken до блоков try/catch.Какое значение надо присвоить ей , чтобы все работало, так как без инициализации компилироваться не будет.Помогите новичку)

Comment: Присвойте `null`

Comment: Я тоже так думал , но null нельзя присвоить неявно типизированной переменно

Comment: А в чем проблема типизировать явно?